# Creating audiobooks from individual tracks

Tags: audiobook

I have the following audiobooks in the latest iTunes under Windows 10:

1. I have imported several audiobooks from Audible into iTunes. Each book appears under "Audiobooks" on my iPod Classic as a single entry.
2. I have also imported several books purchased elsewhere, as individual MP3 files. I have ensured that the title, author, etc. are identical and have numbered all tracks correctly. I have set the Media Kind to "Audiobooks" and have selected the "part of a compilation" option as well as the "skip when shuffling" and "remember position" options. In iTunes, these books appear correctly, each as one entry, with all the tracks in the correct order.
3. I have also imported one original CD audiobook (11 disks) and have curated the meta-data as described above. Again, in iTunes, the book appears correctly.

After syncing to my iPod Classic, all the Audiobooks appear, but only the Audible ones appear as a single entry per book. Each track of each of the MP3 books and the CD book appear as individual entries/books. This makes for a very long list, and, of course, makes it very inconvenient to listen to. I would have to scroll to "Chapter 1" of the book I want, listen to it, and then scroll to "Chapter 2" of the same book, etc. "Chapter 1", "Chapter 2", etc. for each book appears in the audiobook list.

I have searched extensively, but have not found a solution. [This](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/174327/join-merge-consolidate-many-audio-book-cds-into-one-or-a-few-albums-in-itunes-12) answer did not solve the problem I describe.

Comment: (I suppose that I could create a playlist for each audiobook as a workaround.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://oakroadsystems.com/genl/itunsabk.htm#Step3) link suggests using the freeware program called "[Chapter and Verse](http://lodensoftware.com/chapter-and-verse/)" to merge chapters into an audiobook. The latest version is available for [download](http://lodensoftware.com/downloads/). Note that:

```
Chapter and Verse requires that Apple Quicktime
and Windows Media Player be installed to run.
```

and

```
Non-AAC files are automatically converted using iTunes.
```

Comment: I tested the process with a 160kbps MP3 audiobook. The audio quality after conversion to AAC (via iTunes) using the "High Quality" setting was poor; it was even worse using the "Spoken Podcast" setting. Custom settings would not accept bitrates higher that 64kbps, indicating that they were incompatible with the iTunes converter. Using 64kbps, Auto and Mono produced good results, but poorer than the original. The "iTunes Plus" setting produced the best results, but the original was still better. The original file was ~840kb and the AAC file was ~250kb.

Comment: The latest version of "Chapter and Version" (1.5.3.0) is, unfortunately, too buggy to use. It would crash/hang at some point on almost every audiobook conversion. Coupled with the slightly poorer audio quality after conversion to AAC, I consider it a better option to listen to the MP3 files on a different device.

Answer (score 1):

Here in 2017 on Windows 10 64bit installing QuickTime 7.7.9 with all components installed allows Chapter and Verse to run. Otherwise it crashes.
It will however not start iTunes to do conversion and instead gives an error saying "the files cannot be used". For the conversion one must use a program like "fre:ac" to convert to ".m4a" which can then be used in Chapter and Verse.