# How do I merge tracks from audiobooks so they are one file instead of 100 separate tracks?

Tags: itunes, macos, audiobook

Some of my audiobooks download as 1 7-hour long track. Others are in iTunes as 50-100 separate tracks (that sometime get out of order). I would like to merge the tracks so each audiobook appears as one long file/track. How do I do this?

Comment: Related: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/174327/join-merge-consolidate-many-audio-book-cds-into-one-or-a-few-albums-in-itunes-12/174341#174341, but the "Join CD Tracks" option is not shown in my case (probably because I didn't import from CD)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Join-merge-consolidate many audio book CDs into one or a few albums in iTunes 12 / PC?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/174327/join-merge-consolidate-many-audio-book-cds-into-one-or-a-few-albums-in-itunes-12)

Comment: @ʀ2ᴅ2 The OP explicitly states that that does not work

Answer (score 4):

I do this in the terminal with ffmpeg.

1. Install ffmpeg. Download it from https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/, extract the 7z archive, and copy `ffmpeg` to /usr/local/bin. Alternately, if you use Homebrew or MacPorts, you can `brew install ffmpeg` or `sudo port install ffmpeg`, respectively.
2. `cd` into a directory containing all the audiobook segments you want to join together. Make sure the file path does not contain any spaces.
3. Run: `ffmpeg -safe 0 -f concat -i <(for f in $PWD/*.EXT; do echo "file '$f'"; done) -codec copy full.EXT`, replacing both instances of "EXT" with the file extension used by your audiobook (mp3, m4a, etc).

This will, of course, not work with DRM'd audiobooks. The same will be true for any tool that does not strip the DRM.

Comment: +1 for scripted solution instead of leaching online tools.

Comment: @ʀ2ᴅ2 ...which is harder and complicated, plus you have to install more software.

Comment: @MateusRibeiro I disagree and if you're going to be dealing with video modifications it's a good idea to have `ffmpeg` on your box.

Comment: @ʀ2ᴅ2 he is clearly making a standard user question (video modifications? lol) and even for a +25 years of computers like me typing commands is tiresome and far from easy.

Comment: Oh wow someone likes to push their ego around, lol 25 yrs.  There are smart ways to do tasks but if you like to keep typing manual commands so much maybe you should look at automator and assigning shortcuts with scripts.

Comment: For whatever it's worth, I legitimately believe this is the most efficient way to concatenate media. It's a command I use all the time, by copying from an easy-to-access text file. It's faster than navigating the UI of a larger program, and I know for sure that media isn't getting re-encoded (and losing quality). The terminal certainly has a learning curve, but once you know your way around it really is faster for many tasks!

Answer (score 2):

I use the software Audiobook Builder to merge single tracks from an audiobook to one file. Afterwards you can delete the originals if you want. You can find the programm in the Mac App Store.

Comment: I use that program, too.  Just make sure that each (combined) file is under about 10 hours, otherwise iTunes will have problems with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use online tools. There are several websites like Audio Joiner:

1. Choose files to upload. Select which audio files you want to merge.
2. Choose the settings for your output file. After selecting the
       appropriate audios for merging, drag-and-drop them until they are in
       the desired order.
3. Download a single big file.

I belive this is the most convenient method whithout installing anything nor typing several instructions. It will accept different extensions like wav, ogg, wma, m4a, but depending on your files you will have to convert to MP3 prior to uploading. You can do this on iTunes.

Answer (score 1):

I created a free tool (Track Concatenator) to join together iTunes tracks. It uses `ffmpeg` and `mp4v2` to merge files and it adds chapter markers so you can easily skip between the original tracks in the merged file.

More information: https://www.davidschlachter.com/misc/trackconcat

Comment: I will give it a try!